# simplify $c=\sqrt{290-143\sqrt2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am trying to simplify $c=\sqrt{290-143\sqrt2}.$ I am solving a triangle and I got that $c^2=290-143\sqrt2.$ I have tried to use the formula for $\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{b}}$ but it seemed useless at the end. Can you give me a hint? I want to remove the square root.

Comment: Try setting $a(290-143\sqrt 2) = (b+c\sqrt 2)^2$ and solving for $b,c$ in terms or $a$.

Comment: @KaloyanK. can you show us how you´ve obtained $c^2=290-143\sqrt2?$ Are you sure there isn't a typo?

Comment: @KaloyanK. Alright.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to remove the square root and get something of the form $a+b\sqrt c$ where $a,b,c$ are rational numbers. If that were possible, the minimal polynomial of the given number would be quadratic. But that of $\sqrt{290-143\sqrt2}$ is a quartic $x^4-580x^2+43202=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2=290-143\sqrt{2}$$
$$a+b-2\sqrt{ab}=290-143\sqrt{2}$$
so,
$$a+b=290 \quad \text{and} \quad 4ab=2.143^2$$
which is impossible to solve for $a$ and $b$ rational numbers.