# Simplifying $\sqrt{34+15\sqrt2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt{34+15\sqrt2}$$
If we want $34+15\sqrt2$ to be a nice square $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, most likely it is the case that $15\sqrt2$ corresponds to $2ab$. I don't know what to do from here. Is there any general approach that I can use to determine if it can be further simplified?

Comment: There's no guarantee that $\sqrt{34+15\sqrt2}$ can be simplified further.  Do you have a particular reason to believe that it should be?

Comment: Maybe check your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3991305/89922 for an approach?

Comment: See the [nested radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Two_nested_square_roots) formula. In this case, $34^2-15^2\cdot 2$ is not the square of a rational number, so no further simplification is available.

Comment: Can someone explain to me the downvote?

Comment: The only possible simplification would be: $$\sqrt{34+15\sqrt{2}}=2^{1/4}\sqrt{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(19-\sqrt{8}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be $\left(a+\sqrt{2} b\right)^2=34+15 \sqrt{2}$

$a^2+2b^2=34;\;2\sqrt{2}ab=15\sqrt 2\to 2ab=15\to b=\frac{15}{2a} $

$a^2+2\left(\frac{15}{2a}\right)^2=34$

$2 a^4-68 a^2+225=0$

which has no nice solutions, thus $\sqrt{34+15 \sqrt{2}}$ cannot be simplified further.